# Conditionally log trace messages in ASP Core and NLog

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog

Is there a way to log trace messages in the context of an HTTP Request only if an error message is logged? I am looking to reduce the amount of logging but want detailed information if an error should occur somewhere in the request.

Ideally we would use  `ILogger<T>` and TRACE level logging anywhere we want but stop any traces from being logged unless an ERROR log occurred within the context of the HTTP Request

Currently using ASP.NET Core 2.1 and Nlog

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution that will write last 200 log-events on error:

```
  <target name="String" xsi:type="AutoFlushWrapper" condition="level >= LogLevel.Error" flushOnConditionOnly="true">
     <target xsi:type="BufferingWrapper"
          bufferSize="200"
          overflowAction="Discard">
        <target xsi:type="wrappedTargetType" ...target properties... />
     </target>
  </target>
```

Notice `flushOnConditionOnly` was introduced with NLog 4.6.6

It has the unwanted side-effect that log-events from other active requests will be mixed with the trace-messages from the failed request.

See also: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/BufferingWrapper-target

I guess what you really are looking for is this: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/issues/304